# VB ASP.NET sending data to a flash movie

Tags: asp.net, flash, actionscript-3

I have a "label" in a Flash Movie. I need to send a data from the server side and this data must be displayed on the Flash movie.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send data to your Flash Movie from server side. Try the .xml files. It is easy to work with xml files in Adobe Flash. You can edit your XML files via any programming language.